# How to check if your muffler will fit your car

Tags: muffler, seat-ibiza, seat-cars

So i'm thinking about buying a muffler for my 2001 seat ibiza 6K2. I came across a few good ones and after watching some video's about people installing them (mightycarmods for example) i'm really considering to buy one myself.

The reason i would want a muffler is to give my car a bit of a mean and deep sound to it. I was looking at [THIS](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/SEAT-IBIZA-LEON-ALTEA-PERFORMANCE-SPORTS-UNIVERSAL-EXHAUST-BACK-BOX-002-SEAT-/380442630468?pt=UK_CarsParts_Vehicles_CarParts_SM&fits=Car%20Make%3ASeat%7CModel%3AIbiza%7CCars%20Type%3A1.4&hash=item589425d944) for example but the muffler doesnt have any measurments so how would i know if it fits? Also if the muffler does come with measurments how do i know if it fits? What part of my exhaust do i measure?

Comment: Why you just don't buy the one, that is suitable for you car and engine? If you would like to install it your self, you need one with right holder and connector. Else if you just like to buy something without measurement, connector pipe diameter of your muffler should not be smaller then the middle pipe. For the rest your car workshop don't care. They weld the right length and the right holder and the right connector.

Comment: Thats the thing, i want to do as much as possible myself and we have welding equipment (and experience) i was just wondering if i can just buy 'any' muffler and make it fit with all the material that comes with it.

Comment: as the German proverb says: what does not fit is made ​​to fit. a few of experience and few pipes and you can do this

Answer (score 1):

Your specific link says **Inlet: 2"** (which is one dimension you look for) and it includes **Universal Fitting kit (50cm Flexi pipe, Reducer, Clamp and Strap)**.  This means you *probably* wouldn't need to weld anything.  It also says it fits your car.

### General Advice

Look for inlet diameter, outlet diameter, dimensions of muffler, and position of inlet and outlet ports.

**Inlet diameter** is the size of the pipe nub on the muffler.  The existing pipe under the car should already be *expanded* to fit over this nub.  This expansion is usually just a hair over the required diameter size and ~5" deep.  An *exhaust clamp* clamps around the two.

**Outlet diameter** only applies when the muffler is more hidden under the vehicle and a tail pipe (separate piece) is used to route the exhaust out the back.  The same type of *expanding* and bolting together apply here.  The tool to expand this is quite simply called a *tail pipe expander*.

**Dimensions** are the space available under your vehicle.  You can start by measuring the existing muffler and seeing if you have free space in any direction.  Leave 1" of clearance from everything around it.  Mufflers get very hot.

If the muffler is not specifically designed for your car, you will need to fabricate and weld some type of hanger bracket onto the muffler.  That sounds complicated, but is literally: bend 1/2" thick rod in weird way, weld it to a strong point on the muffler.  Some vehicles and mufflers are designed to hold the muffler with a long band of metal clamped around the outside of the muffler.  This is the much simpler method.

**Always buy a replacement muffler clamp.**  Your kit includes one, but it should be noted.  There is a very high likelihood that you will destroy any and all bolts that are attached to your exhaust when you mess with them.

If your buying a muffler and tailpipe separately, you need to buy a muffler clamp for that too.  Your link is for a muffler with an integrated tail pipe, but not all mufflers are like that so sometimes you might want to buy a new tailpipe also (for looks or whatever).

You will *probably* also want to purchase new rubber exhaust hangers.  They can break (go missing) sometimes.

Comment: I realize this a year old, but it didn't have an answer and the title seems like a common question.